# PyObjC app not allowed to access the accessibility API

Tags: python, cocoa, cx-freeze, pyobjc

On OSX Maverick, I have this PyObjC(python3.3) based simple APP

```
test.py

class MyDelegate(NSObject):

def applicationDidFinishLaunching_(self, sender):
    NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask_handler_(NSKeyDownMask, lambda event: NSLog("hello"))
    NSApp.activateIgnoringOtherApps_(YES)

delegate = MyDelegate.alloc().init()
app = NSApplication.sharedApplication()
app.setDelegate_(delegate)

menu = NSMenu.alloc().initWithTitle_("My Menu")
app.setMainMenu_(menu)

window = NSWindow.alloc().initWithContentRect_styleMask_backing_defer_(
    NSMakeRect(0, 0, 100, 100),
    NSTitledWindowMask,
    NSBackingStoreBuffered,
    NO
)

window.setTitle_("my app")
window.makeKeyAndOrderFront_(None)

windowController = NSWindowController.alloc().initWithWindow_(window)


AppHelper.runEventLoop()
```

Ran it with

```
python3 test.py
```

and give accessibility access to Terminal in System Preferences -> Privacy & Security -> Accessibility

I could see the global monitor works.

Then I froze it with cx_Freeze

```
python3 setup.py bdist_mac
```

ends up with

```
build/Test.app
```

with

```
open build/Test.app
```

I'm seeing error in OSX system log

```
universalAccessAuthWarn[546]: AccessibilityAPI: pid 3809, is not allowed to access the accessibility API. Path: /path/to/build/Test.app/Contents/MacOS/test
```

I've enabled access for "test" in "System Preferences" -> "Privacy & Security" -> "Accessibility" which doesn't work.

What I'm missing here?

**UPDATE:
Probably was cx_Freeze's problem, using py2app(0.8) made the global event monitor work. Thanks for Ronald Oussoren's hint (see answer & comment below).**

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why this doesn't work with cx_Freeze, it does work for me with py2app using this setup.py file:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='main',
    app=['test.py'],
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

That is, when I launch the application, give it accessibility access and then relaunch the application I see logging from the application in Console.app.

Comment: Thanks. I'm interested how exactly you launched the app after it's built with py2pp. Did you double clicked it or use the "open" command? It works for me too (with cx_Freeze) if I specifically execute the app executable directly from command line but not when I launch the .app itself.

Comment: I launched the application using “open”.

Comment: I installed py2app a while ago on OSX Maverick with python3 and encountered a problem in my first tries to build: error: No such file or directory: /usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/setuptools-2.1-py3.3.egg/_markerlib/__init__.pyc I wonder if that's fixed at the moment. I didn't manage to fix that previously so I switched to cx_Freeze.

Comment: I’ve used py2app 0.8 (just uploaded) with python3.3 on Mavericks without problems.